# ellipsize enabled line text is cutting from left side

Tags: android

I am writing text description in two lines using TextView. I am using `android:gravity="center"` to centrally aligned two lines & also used `android:maxLines="2"` & `android:ellipsize="end"` attributes in xml file. First line is coming properly but at left side of second line text is getting clipped. If I remove `android:ellipsize="end"` attribute then there is no any text cut. So i am thinking that my problem is because of ellipsize attribute. I tried a lot of experiments to solve this issue, but not succeeded. Can anybody help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, there is an incompatibility between the attributes ellipsize, maxLines and letterSpacing.

I had exactly the same issue, and setting the next line solved the issue.

```
android:letterSpacing="0"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Amazing... You're life savior